# Sort foreach loop result

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to sort it by $distance base in foreach loop in my VIEWS.. so heres my code in Models

```
    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select('*')
                ->from('#__load');

    $db->setQuery($query);               
    $db->query();
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $db->loadObjectList();
```

This is the code in my View where i want to sort it by distance

```
  foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) {  
       $distance = $item->result1 * $item->result2        
  sort($distance)
}

echo $distance
```

result

> 3, 6, 2, 7, 8

i want to show like this

> 2, 3, 6, 7, 8

Comment: o.O you sort inside the foreach loop....

Comment: if distance is numeric value try with sort flag `SORT_NUMERIC `, like `sort($distance, SORT_NUMERIC );` outside of foreach loop

Answer (score 3):

sort works on an array, and what you are doing is you are calling sort on every item in the array which wont work.

What you can do instead is do your foreach loop and then sort after:

```
  $array = [];
  foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) {  
      $distance = $item->result1 * $item->result2;        
      $array[] = $distance;
  }
  sort($array);
  var_dump($array);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: the result if i do that is like this
"Array"

Answer (score 1):

First Convert your result `$this->items` into `(array)$this->items` and then use one of the following function :

```
sort() - sort arrays in ascending order
rsort() - sort arrays in descending order
asort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
ksort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key
arsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value
krsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key
```

and get sorted value.

Comment: my question is how will i do that. in my code, i already did the sort()

Comment: You need to modify the code. I think you need solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here that don't make sense to me, so I'll blindly try to refactor your scripts and put all of the processing in the model where it belongs (you shouldn't be manipulating data in the view).

Untested snippet:

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('result1 * result2')
            ->from('#__load')
            ->orderBy(1);
$db->setQuery($query);               
return $db->loadColumn();
```

Relevant pages to read:

- [How can a query multiply 2 cell for each row MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5693259/2943403)
- [what is this order by 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11353688/2943403)
- https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

I expect that your view will now receive the following sorted and indexed array:

```
$this->items = [2, 3, 6, 7, 8];
```

If you are a Joomla user, come join us at [Joomla Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/). Have a browse [of my answers to `mysql` tagged questions](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12352%20%5Bmysql%5D) for explained examples and best practices.

If you are living in Brisvegas, come to our monthly Joomla User Group Meetup in West End (we aren't scary people).  This is a place where you can leverage an IRL network of people that want to help you grow your skills and get your projects finished.